# viewing the content of stack other than registers

Tags: assembly, gdb

I just wonder how can I see the content of 8(%rsp) using GDB. according to several source that I found after googling several gdb guides, when I try to view the content of register rsp, I can use this command:

```
print/d $rsp
```

will print the address of $rsp. However, when I tried:

```
print/d 8($rsp)
```

I got segmentation fault. when I try:

```
print/d *$rsp+8
```

It said that I couldn't dereference a generic pointer. I also try to use:

```
x/8d $rsp
```

However, I think this command will view 8 numbers below rsp instead of above rsp. am I right? The only reason why I want to view the content of 8($rsp), there is an assembly statement:

```
cmp    0x8(%rsp),%eax
```

any suggestion guys?

Comment: Rsp does not have an address; it has a value that's typically, but not necessarily, interpreted as an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you were extremely close to the solution. The right syntax was simply `print /d *($rsp+8)` or `x /x $rsp+8`.